# How to combine multiple rows of data into a single sting per group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

To preface: I'm new to using Python.

I'm working on cleaning up a file where data was spread across multiple rows. I'm struggling to find a solution that will concatenate multiple text strings to a single cell. The .csv data looks similar to this:

> name,date,description
>
> bundy,12-12-2017,good dog
>
> ,,smells kind of weird
>
> ,,needs to be washed

with one or two blank rows between each entry, too.

The amount of rows used for 'description' isn't consistent. Sometimes it's just one cell, sometimes up to about four. The ideal output turns these multiple rows into a single row of useful data, without all the wasted space. I thought maybe I could create a series of masks by copying the data across a few columns, shifted up, and then iterating in some way. I haven't found a solution that matches what I'm trying to do, though. This is where I'm at so far:

```
#Add column f description stuff and shift up a row for concatenation
DogData['Z'] = DogData['Y'].shift(-1)
DogData['AA'] = DogData['Z'].shift(-1)
DogData['AB'] = DogData['AA'].shift(-1)

#create series checks to determine how to concat values properly
YNAs = DogData['Y'].isnull()
ZNAs = DogData['Z'].isnull()
AANAs = DogData['AA'].isnull()
```

The idea here was basically that I'd iterate over column 'Y', check if the same row in column 'Z' was NA or had a value, and concat if it did. If not, just use the value in 'Y'. Carry that logic across but stopping if it encountered an NA in any subsequent columns. I can't figure out how to do that, or if there's a more efficient way to do this.

What do I have to do to get to my end result? I can't figure out the right way to iterate or concatenate in the way I was hoping to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'''
name,date,description
bundy,12-12-2017,good dog
,,smells kind of weird
,,needs to be washed
'''

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

[image: start]

```
df.fillna(method = 'ffill').groupby([
    'name',
    'date'
]).description.apply(lambda x : ', '.join(x)).to_frame(name = 'description')
```

[image: finish]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow exactly what you mean. I took that text, saved it as a csv file, and successfully read it into a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df
```

Output:

```
    name        date           description
0  bundy  12-12-2017              good dog
1    NaN         NaN  smells kind of weird
2    NaN         NaN    needs to be washed
```

Isn't this the output you require?

Comment: The goal is to get rid of the extra rows and concatenate the text in the description, so the end result looks more like row 0, where description would read "good dog, smells kind of weird, needs to be washed"